# When calling function from another contract via interface, get transaction reverted

Tags: solidity, remix, interfaces

I'm searching everywhere and also looking carefully at my simple code. Of course I'm a newbie but have the feelling that everything is fine on my code (pretty simple):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface Dexes {
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract callingDexInfo {
    address public constant uniswapV2 = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
    Dexes dexAddress = Dexes(uniswapV2);

    function getAllPairs() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 all = dexAddress.allPairsLength();
        return all;
    }
}
```

After deploying and see what is deployed. I first see that it appears "Balance: 0 ETH". After that two blue buttons: getAllPairs and uniswapV2. uniswapV2 works as expected but getAllPairs doesn't give me the allPairsLength from the contract Factory from Uniswap. It should give me a uint256.

What I get is a message on the terminal:

```
revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Can not understand why it is asking to pay for this. It is just read functions. Sorry, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying to some of the supported networks (https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/factory) ?

Comment: Yes! I have taken the Factory contract: 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f and checked on etherscan.io. There it shows the functions I'm trying to call on Read only. That's why I'm confused...

Comment: Could you provide a link to your contract in Etherscan?

Comment: I'm using remix. Enviroment Remix VM (London). Here the Deployed Contract: 0x0fC5025C764cE34df352757e82f7B5c4Df39A836

Comment: When clicking the button "uniswapv2 I get correctly the address I just get the error message when clicking "getAllPairs" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are deploying to Remix's internal VM. That network exists only during your Remix session and is not connected to any external network. It doesn't have Uniswap contracts.

Uniswap is deployed only to the network listed [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/factory). If you want to have it in your Remix network, you have to first deploy it there yourself (which isn't a trivial thing to do). Or then use a testnet which already has Uniswap deployed - you can connect to those through your browser wallet with the "Injected Provider" in Remix.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking your time! I will try to use a testnet and see if it works with "Injected Provider". As said, really appreciate. Wish you a great day!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you. But do you know why the results are different on the goerli test network that in the ethereum mainnet. Should not be the same result? Appreciate

Comment: They are different networks, therefore they have very different contract states. Goerli is a testnet, and data in it is totally different compared to the mainnet. People can do very weird things in a testnet.